# password request has expired

Tags: magento-1.9, password-recovery

I have a Magento 1.9 Site: `Livecopper.co.za`

My issue is the password reset link. I wanted to test my site as a client shopping on the front end.

So I sent a forgotten password email to my emails and clicked on the link. It then tells me to add new password twice. Once I did that it gives me a message that the username is not filled in and the password request has expired.

Comment: @SR_Magento, the post is very old and as I could check that the website link does not seem to be the website in Magento. The website is built in Shopify.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora a lot can happen in 3 years :)

Answer (score 1):

This could have several causes, and its possible a module its interfering.  Have you added any recently? Try disabling all of them but the Magento defaults and see if the problem goes away.

It could also be related to patch 6788 if you applied it recently.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem when I added mandatory Date of birth. Please check, in the admin section - manage customers - account information if all required fields have been filled for the customer you are trying to reset password.

Comment: It is not for a specific customer. If you create an account and then log out of it. Then say forgot password, (so the system does not know who the customer is), then put in your email address linked to the account so the system can identify the customer. That is the email link that is not working.

Comment: I just tried and received an email with new password field empty and without any link to reset. Have you installed any extension?